# Python relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, python-import

```
project
 +
 +--------+app1
 |          +
 |          +-------------+models.py  <---+
 |                                        |
 |                                        |
 |                                        | from ..app1.models import Model
 +--------+app2                           |
 |         +                              |
 |         +--------------+models.py      +
 |
 +
```

I want to import the `Model` class in module `models` from app1 into app2. When attempting to use `from ..app1.models import Model`, I receive the error `Attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")            # or sys.path.append(".")
print (os.getcwd())

from app1.models import ModelClassName
```